# Unity 2020.1.10f1 Package Manager Won't Open

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was working on one of my projects and meanwhile, I wanted to download a package and I noticed that the Package Manager would not open. I read forums written to have the com.unity.package-manager-ui in the manifest.json file, I didn't have it. Once I put it in, I became aware of 600 error messages. Then I checked your official unity project on GitHub but there was no package-manager there either. I reinstalled Unity and Unity Hub, but it still didn't open and my manifest file didn't include package-manager-ui either. If anyone could help solve the problem I would be very grateful!

Comment: I'm suggesting that stick to the lower version for stability :)

Comment: Reset the UI of unity it could be it is opening just not where you think it should

Comment: @BugFinder Than you very much, my problem is solved!